# How to correctly determine name after successfully finding a string in another df in R

Tags: r

Good day everyone

I have two data frames defined as

```
  search_for <- tibble(country= c("US - Texas","CA","UK - London-123","US -NY",'MX','Japan' )) 
  country_names <- tibble( names= c('GB','US','US','UK'))
```

I have successfully been able to search for the presence of a country name in the df search_for using

```
search_for$t_f <- mapply(function(x){
    any(country_names$names %in% strsplit(x, split=" ")[[1]])
  }, search_for$country)
  
  search_for
```

which outputs

```
country         t_f  
  <chr>           <lgl>
1 US - Texas      TRUE 
2 CA              FALSE
3 UK - London-123 TRUE 
4 US -NY          TRUE 
5 MX              FALSE
6 Japan           FALSE
```

In the true instances i now want to make a column which shows the country name. To do so I used

```
 search_for$clean_name <- ifelse(mapply(function(x){
    any(country_names$names %in% strsplit(x, split=" ")[[1]])
  }, search_for$country)==TRUE,country_names$names,'Name not in search_for')
  
  search_for
```

which outputted

```
country         t_f   clean_name            
  <chr>           <lgl> <chr>                 
1 US - Texas      TRUE  GB                    
2 CA              FALSE Name not in search_for
3 UK - London-123 TRUE  US                    
4 US -NY          TRUE  UK                    
5 MX              FALSE Name not in search_for
6 Japan           FALSE Name not in search_for
```

The variable clean_name is incorrect as the 3 true instances should read US, UK, US and not GB, US, UK.

The error seems to be due to the fact that its populating the clean_name column in the same order as the names in the df country_names are, and not based on the condition I spoke about.  How do I go about correcting this?

*Please note that this is sample and my actual data has 15k+ rows and its not always the case that the first sub string in country is a country abbreviation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

search_for |>
  mutate(clean_names = str_extract(country, str_c("\\b", country_names$names, "\\b", collapse = "|")),
         t_f = !is.na(clean_names),
         clean_names = replace(clean_names, !t_f, "Name not in search_for"))
```

This works by using a regular expression to extract the words "US", "GB", etc. This regular expression is case sensitive (e.g., will not match "us", "gb") but that is easily changed if needed. Matching within a word boundary (`\\b`) ensures that "US" is not matched in MASSACH**US**ETTS.

This is more flexible because it will match "US Texas", "US-Texas", "US - Texas", etc.

**Output**

```
  country         clean_names            t_f  
  <chr>           <chr>                  <lgl>
1 US - Texas      US                     TRUE 
2 CA              Name not in search_for FALSE
3 UK - London-123 UK                     TRUE 
4 US -NY          US                     TRUE 
5 MX              Name not in search_for FALSE
6 Japan           Name not in search_for FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I had a follow up query. Is there any way to edit the code so that if a minimum of n letters occur then it will match? For instance in your example you gave 'Massachusetts'. Imagine a case where someone spells it wrong in multiple ways say with only 1 't' etc. How would you suggest treating with this?

Comment: @ianaj This is a great thing to post as a new question. You should look into the `fuzzyjoin` package. This uses fuzzy matching algorithms to find approximate matches to merge a data set. You can also do regular expression joins. Perhaps there are simpler approaches, but hard to say without a reproducible example.